# About docker swarm mode with filters, strategy, affinity, etc

Tags: docker-swarm-mode

I've started using docker swarm mode, and I couldn't find reliable information about a lot of things covered in traditional swarm. Does anyone know about the following things??

1. What kind of filters are available? Used to have constraint, health, and containerslots, but not sure how to set, change or use that filter when creating services. I got constraint label working by passing "--constraint node.labels.FOO==BAR" to docker service create, but not sure about other filters.
2. How do you set affinity, dependency, port? passing "-e" doesn't seemed to be working..
3. Anyway to set strategy...?
4. Not specific to swarm, but is there any way to check how much CPU or memory is reserved by containers? Couldn't find relevant information in docker info.
5. This question is also not specific to swarm. Is there any way to limit disk and network bandwidth?

I'm referring this => https://docs.docker.com/swarm/scheduler/filter/ but I can't find one for the swarm mode.
Seriously should be working on improving swarm mode documentation...

Answer (score -1):

Question 1, 2 and 3 can be answered in the following link I believe
https://docs.docker.com/engine/swarm/manage-nodes/

For 4th question:

You can very well do docker inspect on the containers to get cpu and memory reserved. By default docker doesn't assign limit to memory and cpu, it will try to consume what ever is available on the host. If you have set the limits then you can see the same through docker inspect.